# how to make a delay between two ConstraintSet?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, delay, android-motionlayout

i want to make a activity with about 5 ConstraintSet and i want to make a delay when it want go from 3th ConstraintSet to 4th,after 15second,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlm61.png)

is anybody there to know how to do that?